Kotlin equivalent of C# new() generic constraint
Is there an equivalent to the following C# code in Kotlin?
public T New<T>() where T:new()
{
    return new T();
}

I'm aware I can use reflection to construct types at runtime as well as perform error checking, is that the best alternative?

How would you like to use it in Kotlin? Can you add some pseudo-code example?

You cannot do the same in Kotlin. How about taking a () -> T as a parameter?

@t3chb0t Ultimately this is for something like a dependency injection container to construct object graphs at runtime.

This is not possible in Kotlin for two reasons:

Type erasure. Function doesn't even "know" the T, so it is not possible to construct it.
No construct similar to where T:new() which would ensure a class has a no-arg constructor.

We can workaround the first problem to some degree by using reified types and reflection:
fun main() {
    val foo: Foo = create()
    val bar: Bar = create()
}

class Foo
class Bar

inline fun <reified T> create(): T {
    return T::class.constructors.single { it.parameters.isEmpty() }.call()
}

This is far from ideal. We still can't call the function from a fully generic context. If a class doesn't have a no-arg constructor, it will throw at runtime. And reflection should be avoided if possible.
Much more typical pattern in Kotlin is to provide an explicit producer:
fun main() {
    val foo = create(::Foo)
}

fun <T> create(producer: () -> T): T = producer()

Depending on your specific case, you could be able to apply this pattern or it may be not very useful for you.

Thanks, but I have two questions. 1) why is type erasure the issue? I'm asking about a compile time feature and type erasure is something that happens as a result of compilation 2) why should reflection be avoided if possible?

@IanNewson 1. Maybe "type erasure" isn't a perfect wording here, but even at the compile time we don't know what's T, so we can't instantiate it. I'm not very familiar with C#: if this where T:new() is more like a syntactic sugar for implicitly passing a "producer", then I think a direct equivalent in Kotlin is to pass a producer explicitly. But if we can call this New method from any generic context, then this is not possible in Kotlin, because we don't know T. 2. Mostly performance, but generally it is invented for more "special" needs, .e.g. developing frameworks of some sort, etc.

@IanNewson 1. Also, even if the compiler would perform an analysis of some sort and know potential types for T, this still doesn't solve the problem. We need to create an instance at the runtime, when the type is already erased and we see only T/Any in the bytecode. Bytecode doesn't "know" what to instantiate if we don't explicitly pass a class, producer or something similar.
